# unable create autoupdate for an google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am Developing a google chrome extension. I need to provide the auto update for my extension.I am also following the **developer.chrome.com/extensions/autoupdate** but  my extension is not updating  I am trying with command   **--extensions-update-frequency**  and i will also check with the `chrome.runtime.requestUpdateCheck()` it   returns status as **'throttled'**
my manifest file:

```
   {
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name":"Notification",
  "description": "To notify the Mail count",
  "version": "1.0",
   "update_url": "http://localhost/ext/updates.xml",
"background": {
  "scripts":["popup.js"]
  },
    "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup":"popup.html"
  },
    "icons": {
    "256": "icon.png"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "tabs",
  "bookmarks",
  "http://*/*",
  "https://*/*",
  "unlimitedStorage",
  "background",
  "notifications"
  ]
}
```

and my updates.xml :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<gupdate xmlns='http://www.google.com/update2/response' protocol='2.0'>
  <app appid='eimjaaebemfnanomhcgnljegahiiffdk'>
    <updatecheck codebase='http://localhost/ext/note_v2.crx' version='2.0' />
  </app>
</gupdate>
```

and my new extension is also in same directory..

Please any one help me

Thanks in advance..............

Comment: Hey did you find answer for this?